# Make render call using a URL argument to construct the template file name

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm essentially looking to pass arguments from the url into my render request.

for purely demonstration purposes, the equivalent of:

```
return render(request,'clients/models/{{client}}-{{report}}.json',context,content_type = 'application/json')
```

I've already got the variables passed in from url.py to view.py

Thanks in advance for your help!

*NB: technically client and report are objects with their `__unicode__` returning a string. If that's not acceptable, the string is stored as client.slug and report.slug*

Comment: Can you not just parse them out in the view and add them to the context dict?

Comment: I just deleted an answer I posted because I'm really confused as to what you're trying to accomplish.  You have values passed from your url.py to your views and... you want those values to be available to your template?  If so that is straightforward.  If you want to show a custom url then you need to use a redirect.  Otherwise the url will show as the one that was parsed in your url.py file.  If you're trying to use arguments to generate your reference you should be able to just use `"clients/models/{}--{}.json".format(client, report)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to use template syntax here. In the view, you're in Python: you can use normal Python functionality - in this case, string interpolation:

```
return render(request, u'clients/models/%s-%s.json' % (client, report), ...)
```

Comment: Not trying to use template syntax, was just the easiest way to explain what I was trying to do. Thanks for your answer. Somehow I didn't think to revert to Python.